# Finding $B$ matrix from given multiples $Bv=w$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I was asked this question:

> There's a square matrix $B$ from order $3 \times 3$, and we're given that:
> $$
> B
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 2 \\
> 3
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 2 \\
> 3
> \end{pmatrix}$$
> $$
> B\begin{pmatrix}
> -1 \\
> -1 \\
> -2
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 3 \\
> 3 \\
> 2
> \end{pmatrix}$$
> $$
> B\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 1 \\
> 3
> \end{pmatrix}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 \\
> 1 \\
> -1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> 1. Is B invertible?
> 2. Find B.

I was thinking on finding first B and then if the determinant of $B$ is not $0$ then $B$ is indeed invertible. But I've been stuck on finding $B$ for quite some time now.

I tried different ways to approach this, First I tried something like this:
$$
B
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
And I thought maybe if I get the inverse of the middle matrix and multiplied it with the second matrix it will result in B, like this:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}=B$$
Which was incorrect, and then I thought maybe I organized the vectors in the matrix incorrectly, so I tried to transpose it, but still was incorrect.

So I gave up on this way, and tried a different way:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
But I wasn't sure how to continue from here.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you indeed organized incorrectly the vectorial information you had when converting it to a matrix equality. Your three assumptions yield (the vectors must remain vertical)
$$
B \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 2 & -1 & 1 \\ 3 & -2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is an equality of the form $B A = C$, which indeed fully determines the matrix $B$ you are looking for if $A$ is invertible. Multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}$, you will then have $BA A^{-1} = C A^{-1}$, so $B = C A^{-1}$ (beware that matrix multiplication does not commute so you have to be cautious on which side you are multiplying).

Checking that $\det A \neq 0$, computing $A^{-1}$, computing $C A^{-1}$, and eventually $\det B$ should be a standard exercise for you.

Comment: I tried to organize it this way too, but I totally forgot that matrix multiplication isn't commute. Thank you so much!